# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

I get the error above in my Eclipse signed web applet. I would appreciate any help..

It states that my class is not found:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/dermalog/common/exception/DermalogException
```

Although I have images as proof that it is included in the build:

[Image1](http://s13.postimg.org/pz83ik5d3/image.jpg)
[Image2](http://s13.postimg.org/m44pfzm7b/image.jpg)

How I added my jar files:

1. Made a "lib" folder
2. Copied the jar files into the "lib" folder
3. clicked "Properties" on the project
4. Went to build path, libraries
5. Added the jar reference

Comment: How do you run your applet?

Comment: I run it through a web page...

Comment: Does the same happen if you run it from Eclipse (right click the project -> Run As -> Java applet)?

Comment: I unfortunately cannot test it like that, as it needs a lot of interaction from the browser. I will try to build a separate applet to see if the problem persists.

Comment: I have created a separate applet, It runs perfectly fine in Eclipse, but as soon as it is exported, it delivers the same problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a jar to project Java Build Path in an Eclipse project in most cases only means to add it to classpath used for compilation. Items set on build path are also used to create classpath when running your application or applet from within Eclipse.

The build path however does not say anything about the classpath of your applet when it runs in a different context, e.g. on a webpage. There, one needs to make sure that classpath contains all jars needed to run the app.

There are two simple ways to do this:

- [Add a manifest file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) to your JAR and specify the classpath (required JARs) there. Then, when deploying / copying your JAR to the location where it is being invoked, copy the dependency JARs as well.
- Include all classes from the JARs your applet depends on to your applet's JAR. Eclipse's Export function allows this.

EDIT:
Ok, I checked your jar file and found this:

- MANIFEST.MF had no classpath definition. It should contain a line like:

`Class-path: dermalog.afis.drawing.compression.jar dermalog.afis.fingercode.jar dermalog.imaging.capturing.jar`

- The dependency jars should not be packaged in the dependant jar. Instead, they should be just placed in the same directory (or in a subdirectory - but then use that subdirectory in classpath as well).

The page I linked above explains that.

Comment: Thanks David, I will try the manifest file.
Currently my .classpath file looks like this
[link](http://s13.postimg.org/wi7vlotkn/image.jpg)

Comment: I could host the jar and the html running it if you would be so kind as to have a quick look?

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Thanks for giving up some of your time to help me on this.. Having years of C# experience, this is a slightly different concept to me, but it now makes complete sense and works perfectly.. :-)

Comment: Is there any way to export the referenced jar files within the main jar file and still have them referenced?

Comment: Technically, there is. You can just unpack the classes from referenced jars and pack them to your JAR. Eclipse JAR export has an option to do that, you can do it in an ant script as well. However, if these are 3rd party jars, I'd check license  agreements of the jars first.